# Change office ribbon run time

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbonx

I have a word add on project with two ribbon.xml files. What I need to do is change the current ribbon at run time.

the method  DocumentBase.CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()  can use to do the job. But I cannot find way to trigger this method at run time.
when app starts this method triggers.

```
 protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility reateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
        {
            if (condition == true)
            {

                return Ribbon1;
            }
            else
            {
                return Ribbon2;
            }


        }
```

I need to change the current ribbon of application at run time

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design. The Ribbon XML used *must* be pre-defined when a project is loaded; it cannot be changed or created at run-time.

It's possible to dynamically display or enable controls using call-backs. Labels and images on controls can also be loaded dynamically. Lists and dynamic menus can be populated dynamically. Put all you could ever need in the Ribbon XML at design time then hide/disable what should not be available by default.

(Responding to follow-up in comments) Also by design, it's not possible to work with third-party Ribbon customizations. Too many developers were manipulating both built-in and third-party menus and toolbars - users thought the Office application was "buggy" because things were disappearing/changing. So the Ribbon UI only allows accessing third-party controls *if* those have been purposely "shared" (by using the `idQ` attribute).

Comment: Thanks Cindy. But is there a way I can show Hide third party add - on tabs like Acrobat tab

Comment: @tilankakulatunge Short answer: no. More information added to the answer.